# Embedding YouTube videos in CartoDB infowindows?

Tags: carto, infowindow, youtube

I need a tutorial for how to embed YouTube videos in [CartoDB Editor](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-editor/) infowindows.

[Most help](https://gist.github.com/andrewxhill/8655774) I can find about this is about iframes which were apparently disabled for security reasons.

What do I have to do, step by step, to make an infowindow display a YouTube video in CartoDB Editor?

What is the HTML code I have to put in the infowindow section of the CartoDB web interface?

Is this possible without hosting the map on my own server? How do I access the .js script if I am using the CartoDB Editor web interface?

This, from the aforementioned link, does not work:

```
<div class="cartodb-popup">
  <a href="#close" class="cartodb-popup-close-button close">x</a>
  <div class="cartodb-popup-content-wrapper">
    <p>
     <iframe width="188" src="{{youtube_embed_link}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="cartodb-popup-tip-container"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CartoDB disables < script > and < iframe > tags on infowindows due to security reasons. However, you could still disable this, by using the `sanitizeTemplate:false`option when declaring an infowindow, like this: 

`sublayer.infowindow.set({
    template: $('#infowindow_template').html(),
    width: 218,
    maxHeight: 100,
    sanitizeTemplate:false
  });`

You can check that out [on the documentation](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html#sublayerinfowindow)